# Import data in CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a CSV file of AD users and I manually added one column with a global ID to the file. I need to import that global ID column for all the users in the file to the `employeeNumber` field in my AD accounts.

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\work\test.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_.displayname
    $employeeNumber = $_.employeeNumber

    Get-AdUser -Filter {displayname -eq $user} |
        Set-ADUser -EmployeeNumber $employeeNumber
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you replace `Set-ADuser -employeeNumber $employeeNumber ` with `Write-Host $employeeNumber` do you get a list of the numbers you expect?

Comment: no it giving me supply the values of parameters :

Comment: actually I need to add just one column data to my ad accounts

Comment: Your code works perfectly as I have just tested it.  I can see a few revision edits ago the code formatting was slightly incorrect as detailed in the answer by @vrdse however this has since been corrected.  Ensure the headings in the csv are actually as expected: "employeenumber" and "displayname".  After running the code check for one of the users    `get-aduser $user -properties employeenumber` - is it populated as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your filter syntax will work.

Try this:
`Get-ADUser -Filter 'displayName -like "$user"'`

Also, you may have to load the property that you want to edit. I don't know for sure but you might toss in a:

`-properties employeeNumber`

on your Get-AdUser call to ensure that Set-AdUser can see that property.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Cmdlet `Foreach-Object`. This cmdlet expects a value for the parameter `-Procees`. You do not have to name the parameter - it can be called as a positional paramter, too. BUT a new line is not allowed for Cmdlet parameters.

You either have to use `foreach`, which is a keyword or remove the new line before the opening curley braket.